# Is this a structure in typescript?

Tags: typescript

I have the following structure coming from a server :

```
   {
            "0": {
                    /// itemparams
            },
            "1": {
                    /// itemparams
            },
            "2": {
                    /// itemparams
            },
            "3": {
                    /// itemparams
            }
    }
```

I would like to type it to something, At first I thought this was a `Map<string, itemParams>` but it throw me an error of unmatching type.

what is a way to type it ?

Comment: Can you please add more code what is itemParams, and it's structure and where you are facing an issue. ? How you are using it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not a `Map<string, itemParams>`. `Map` is an es6 map : https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map

What you have is a simple object with with string keys and values of `itemParams`.

You can use a [string indexer](https://basarat.gitbooks.io/typescript/docs/types/index-signatures.html):

```
{[key:string]: itemParams}
```

Answer (score 0):

Personal preference depends on the real-world use case but ideally `Record<string, itemParams>`